# Upgrading ffmpeg

Tags: apt, software-installation, upgrade

How can I upgrade `ffmpeg` to version 0.6 on debian-based operating system?

I'm using apt-get for installation and deb packages.

Comment: Is the problem here that that version of ffmpeg is not in the normal repositories?

Comment: When I run `apt-get install ffmpeg` it writes me that my package is already the newest version but it isn't. I need version 0.6.

Comment: I recommend installing from source. Last time I checked Debian and Ubuntu shipped unusable versions of ffmpeg (and mplayer) so I do that anyway. You can still get the dependencies with `apt-get build-dep ffmpeg`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debian [currently carries ffmpeg](http://packages.debian.org/ffmpeg) versions [0.5.2 in stable (squeeze)](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/ffmpeg), [0.6.2 in testing (wheezy)](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/ffmpeg) and [in unstable](http://packages.debian.org/sid/ffmpeg). There's also a [0.7 package in experimental](http://packages.debian.org/experimental/ffmpeg). Ubuntu [currently carries](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ffmpeg) versions [0.5.1 in lucid (Ubuntu 10.04)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/ffmpeg) and [0.6.2 in natty (Ubuntu 11.04)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/ffmpeg), and [0.7 in oneiric (in alpha-testing)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/ffmpeg).

If you're running squeeze, 0.5.2 is the newest version *of the package for squeeze*. Debian makes no promise that they'll always have the latest version of every software, and fact the very premise of the [stable release](http://www.debian.org/releases/) is that program versions are not updated during the lifecycle of the stable release. Similarly, 0.5.1 is the newest version of the package for lucid, which is a long-time support release of Ubuntu (no package upgrades unless absolutely necessary).

The [Debian multimedia](http://www.debian-multimedia.org/) repository currently has 0.6.1 for squeeze. Generally if you want more recent versions or more features in multimedia packages, you should use that repository.

In general, if you want more recent versions, you can try recompiling the [source package](http://packages.debian.org/source/wheezy/libav) from testing or unstable on squeeze. The dependencies look ok. (Also, you can find some backports of testing packages to stable in the [backports repository](http://www.backports.org/), but there isn't one for ffmpeg at this time.) For Ubuntu, similarly, grab the source package from a more recent distribution and try recompiling; or look for a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas); there are many [offering ffmpeg](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=ffmpeg) (not all of them offer current versions, and some of the matches don't have `ffmpeg` but only software that interoperates with it).

Comment: Actually I'm using Xubuntu 10.04. I didn't know that the version of ffmpeg is dependent on version of Debian or Ubuntu.

Comment: @xralf Unless your distribution is a “rolling release” (i.e. always get the latest software, whether it's broken or not), you get whatever version was current when the package for your release was made, i.e. whatever version of the software was current a little before the distribution shipped.

Comment: @xralf: so what did you chose actually?

Comment: @Philomath I will try recompiling and hope it will work.